# How to add/append React Element within LI(any) DOM element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a file system application using React, i am new to React. 
I want to create tree view dynamically on click.
And on each click an API call is make and on the basis of its response i am creating JSX element using map fucntion ;

Here is the JS code for creating element:

```
           (key).map((child, index) => { return <li key={index}
                onClick={(e) => { this.onClickHandler(child); this.expandList(key, e) }}>
                {child.type === 'DIR' ? <FolderIcon className="icon-class"></FolderIcon> :
                    <InsertDriveFile className="icon-class"></InsertDriveFile>}
                <a href="#">{child.name}</a>
                <ul className="u-padding-left-12">

                </ul>
            </li>
        })
    }
```

I want this element to be appended within LI.
Can anyone help me on this. 
Thank You!

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/chenglou/react-treeview simple tree view in react

Comment: i have tried that , but not fit to my requirement .Becz for the child node i have to make an API call to get the child folder or file. And after that want to append that newly created element withing the parent element. For creating child element i am using above JSX code

Comment: Are you using redux ?

Comment: Nope not using .Actually the error i m getting because i am using the 
parent.appendChild(<JSX/React Element>).

Comment: the above map function returns array with 3 elements .. similar to this

{$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: "li", key: "0", ref: null, props: {…}, …}

Comment: Can create a sandbox / fiddle to help me help you :D